# How can I create the OK button of keyboard in a UIWebview form?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uiview, uiwebview

This blue "OK" button is common in a UIWebview when you click in a [webform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_%28web%29) at iPhone.

[image: The blue OK button]

Are there a easy way to recreate it in code? Or I will have to create it in a hard way?

The most close code was:

```
    UISegmentedControl *buttonOK = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"OK"]];
    [buttonOK setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [buttonOK setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.25f green:0.51f blue:0.95f alpha:1.0f]];
    [buttonOK setFrame:CGRectMake(276, 8, 38, 30)];
```

But isn't the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button in the web view uses a translucent UIToolbar with a done button style:

```c
UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Previous", @"Next", nil]];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

UIBarButtonItem* segmentedControlItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done:)];
UIBarButtonItem* flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:NULL];
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
toolbar.translucent = YES;
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:segmentedControlItem, flexSpace, item, nil];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Comment: Great idea! This is a UIBarButtonItem :)

Comment: And about the "Anterior"/"Seguinte" (Next, previous) button. Is just a UISegmentedControl or is a UIBarButtonItem ? I do a thing equal to that, but wasn't the same.

Comment: It's a UISegmentedControl wrapped in a UIBarButtonItem.  I've updated the code in my post to include it.